# Calculating AICc value from Maxent output

Tags: r, maxent

I want to calculate the AICc value for my Maxent models. On a little search, I have found that calc.aicc function if implemented in R, can help in finding out the AICc value. But, I am not sure, what should be the input parameters. The link of the function is: https://rdrr.io/cran/ENMeval/man/calc.aicc.html

```
calc.aicc(nparam, occ, predictive.maps)

get.params(model)
```

I know that occ is the occurence records and predictive maps might be referring to the ASCII file generated by the Maxent but I am not sure about the other parameters, like what is meant by `model` here etc.

Comment: The documentation you provide states the following for the `model` parameter: "A Maxent model object generated by the maxent function in the dismo package." Does this answer your question?

Comment: I have got the maxent output by using GUI not by dismo package

Comment: Could you please edit your question with how you implemented Maxent? Also, how is the arcgis-desktop tag pertinent to your question? Thanks for the clarification.